# How to resize an icon in React-Native (Expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo

I wanted to remove the text like "Home" and "Explore" from this:

```
 StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#fff');

  if (home) {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#fff');
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content');
    }
  } else {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false);
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    labeled={false}
      shifting={false}
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: home ? '#000' : '#fff',
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor={home ? '#fff' : '#000'}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        listeners={{
          focus: () => setHome(true),
          blur: () => setHome(false),
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="home" size={32} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Discover"
        component={Discover}
        options={{
           tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={30} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

and I changed the `size` from `fontawesome` and `antdesign` to `32`/`30`. Now my icons are bigger, but the icon is incomplete. The icon is cut in half. I think I need to use `padding`, but I don't have styles for this. Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are placing them inside the TabNavigator, for them to enter you have to make the TabNavigator bigger, like this:

```
tabBarOptions={{
   style:{height:300}
}}
```

so your code:

```
StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content');

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#fff');

  if (home) {
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#fff');
      StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content');
    }
  } else {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false);
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    labeled={false}
      shifting={false}
      barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: home ? '#000' : '#fff',
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor={home ? '#fff' : '#000'}
      tabBarOptions={{
        style:{height:300}
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        listeners={{
          focus: () => setHome(true),
          blur: () => setHome(false),
        }}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="home" size={100} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Discover"
        component={Discover}
        options={{
           tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={50} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I see this error on console: `No overload matches this call.`  `Property 'tabBarOptions' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Props, "style" | "shifting" | "labeled" | "renderTouchable" | "activeColor" | "inactiveColor" | "sceneAnimationEnabled" | "keyboardHidesNavigationBar" | "barStyle" | "theme" | "backBehavior"> & DefaultRouterOptions<...> & { ...; }'.` I can't put all the code here because it's too long

Comment: That's a Typescript error, just search for the Props and put them